# How to connect AWS cognito and VK social network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, openid, vk

I use AWS stack in BE for mobile App. I have an AWS Cognito User Pool and already has organized authentication throw Google, Facebook and Apple. Now I need to implement/configure authentication throw VK social network. VK doesn't support OpenID but it supports OAuth 2.0.

Unfortunately, I don't understand how can I implement it. Please share you experiance.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is only about authorization. There is no authentication here. So to implement what you need you either have to implement the authentication yourself (and expose an OIDC token to Cognito), or use a third-party solution that can do it for you (whether it's paid or not).

While describing how to build you own OIDC wrapper for OAuth would be a topic for at least a few blog posts, what I can suggest is to use an existing solutions that could integrate with VK.

On of those solutions is Auth0 (and no, I'm not associated with them in any way). It has a connector for vKontakte.

You basically need to chain the flow like that:

1. Configure Auth0 to authenticate with VK
2. Configure Cognito with Identity Pool and an OIDC connector with Auth0

This will work as follows:

1. You call Cognito's UI which will redirect you to Auth0
2. On Auth0 you will have a button to redirect to VK
3. After successful sign in you will be redirected to Auth0 and there you will have a new user
4. Auth0 will redirect back to Cognito and it will sync user data from Auth0 to your User Pool

That's just an example and there are probably more providers that could do the same thing.